# Creating macro and rearrange the result tab in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

I am new in creating macros in excel. I am generating report from sql developer and creating excel files.

Now i want to create macro and rearrange my result in excel. For this i am thinking to create button in excel and after clicking on button.

I am not sure whether its possible to do in excel macro. I am using office version 2016.

Comment: To answer the question "is it possible," very much so **Yes**.  If you can, please use the Macro Recorder in the Developer tab of Excel to start working through building how you want, then try modifying that code.  When you've an issue with that coding, please bring it back to Stack Overflow for help with the specific coding issue.

Comment: For things to look for in Excel-VBA, you should check out looping (can loop through each cell in Column A for "name" or isempty()) to delete the rows.  You could also take the approach of using Find/FindNext for each instance of the headers.

Comment: This can also be done with formulas if you use one sheet for your SQL dump and the second sheet as the final display sheet. You will not need VBA in this case.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman in this case after creating excel file from report i have to provide button so after clicking on that it will create new sheet with the result i want right ?

Comment: If you want to use a template you can copy the newly created SQL report into template and formulas will update with new data.

Comment: this looks difficult to me but i will give try as i am new to it

Answer (score 1):

Could you just combine within your SQL with something like:

```
SELECT 
i.name, i.id, id.date, id.import,
e.export,
v.volume

FROM IMPORT AS i
LEFT JOIN EXPORT AS e ON i.date = e.date
LEFT JOIN VOLUME AS v ON i.date = v.date
```

I'm new to SQL but slowly getting used to writing queries so hopefully I haven't made any mistakes in my suggestion.

OR if you still wish to do in Excel, the following will do the trick

**Assumption:** running the macro from within the correct workbook and with the correct worksheet active

```
Sub consolidateOutput()

' note: this presumes your import data will always be on the first row

Dim exportStartRow, volumeStartRow, lastRow As Integer

lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' finds the last row with data in column D

For i = 1 To lastRow ' loop through column D from the 1st row until the last row with data
    If Range("D" & i).Value = "export" Then '
        exportStartRow = i ' set the row number where you found "export"
    ElseIf Range("D" & i).Value = "volume" Then
        volumeStartRow = i ' set the row number where you found "volume"
        GoTo exitLoop
    End If
Next i

exitLoop:

' using the row numbers you found above, select and then past the export data
Range("D" & exportStartRow & ":D" & volumeStartRow - 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("E1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
' using the row numbers you found above, select and then past the volume data
Range("D" & volumeStartRow & ":D" & lastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("F1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```